# Does GCC have a GUI?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, gcc, ide

Does GCC have a GUI or Graphical IDE?

Edit:

I'm on Windows Vista /7 OR Ubuntu 9.10. I'm looking for something beginner-friendly. I've used Flash CS3 for 2 years and been doing HTML for 6. I have toyed briefly with Java and once or twice tried C++. I prefer working on Windows for now.

Comment: Umm... Should you remove objective-c tag then?

Comment: No, I'm looking to use it for Objective-C

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Plenty. Just to name a few, in no particular order:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

  [image: Eclipse Screenshot]
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)

  [image: KDevelop Screenshot]
- [Anjuta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/)

  [image: Anjuta Screenshot]
- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

  [image: MonoDevelop Screenshot]
- [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)

  [image: Code::Blocks Screenshot]
- [Qt Creator](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Category:Tools::QtCreator)

  [image: Qt Creator Screenshot]
- On Mac, [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/)

  [image: Xcode Screenshot]
- On Windows, [Dev-C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)

  [image: Dev-C++ Screenshot]
- Not real IDEs but still very popular development environments: [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

(As notnoop has noted, there is no *official* IDE but there are many standalone IDE applications that support targeting GCC)

Comment: Qt Creator would be a welcome addition to this excellent list.  :)

Answer (score 14):

No.  gcc is a compiler!  There are many IDEs that use gcc underneath the hood.

The choice of the IDE is dependent on the language you desire.  For Objective-C, pretty much the only supported IDE is [XCode on Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode).  XCode is bundled with Mac OS X (at least available for free online).

Answer (score 2):

gcc is just a compiler, not an IDE.

On Windows you can use its MinGW port.

On Linux IDEs like emacs,vim,geany,code::blocks,netbeans use gcc as their compiler.
On Windows IDEs like Dev-Cpp, Code::Blocks, etc support MinGW port of gcc

**EDIT :**

ON **Windows** you can use **Code::Blocks**(my favourite) that comes bundled along with MinGW compiler or you can also use **MSVC++** IDE(but I think it has a broken compiler :P)