# IDE for gcc compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does GCC have a GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987868/does-gcc-have-a-gui)

I've downloaded MinGW and I require an IDE for compiler.
I'm going for eclipse atm, which one would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is good.

Netbeans is good.

DevC++ is good.

Now you choose :-)

Comment: I thought DevC++ hasn't been updated for years?

Comment: is Code::Blocks not on your good IDE list?

Comment: @user15353 never tried it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is quite good, haven't tried any other IDE so can't comment further

Answer (score 2):

[QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) also has a lot of nice capabilities.

I would avoid Dev-C++ because the compiler is horribly outdated, and it has been dead for a long time

Answer (score 1):

I have used [DevC++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html) and I have heard good words for [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/).

Answer (score 0):

- Emacs along with [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) is good!
- Eclipse along with [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) is fine!

Comment: @user15353 C/C++ Development Tooling. Have you checked that link?

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio supports choosing your own compiler and build system, so it should work with gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216025/gcc-with-visual-studio), but I haven't used the combination myself.

Comment: This is shooting yourself in the foot: there would be no debugging, error on lineXX->source click shortcut etc... not a good idea. Every other IDE has more support for GCC IMHO.

Comment: OK ... good to know.  Still VS can serve as a smart viewer for your code base.