# How to compile C++ files organized in a directory structure?

Tags: c++, compilation, code-organization

I've written a bunch of code now, and sorted it in a fashion similar to this outline:

```
project/
+ include/
| + bar/
| |   bar.hpp
|   foo.hpp
+ src/
| + bar/
| |   bar.cpp
|   foo.cpp
|   main.cpp
```

My question is, how do I call `g++` now, so that it links everything together nicely?

I've already figured out that I need to call it with the `-I` option pointing to the include/ directory. I'm guessing it would make most sense calling g++ from the project/ folder. Also, I'm considering writing a Makefile to automate this process, but I have to admit I haven't done very much research on that yet.

Comment: how do you include, say bar.hpp from bar.cpp?

Comment: @Sam: So far I'm only using `g++`, I'm currently reading up on Makefiles (using the GNU Make manuals)

Comment: @thbusch: I include bar.hpp from bar.cpp using `#include "bar/bar.hpp"`. I figured this should work since I tell the compiler about the include/ directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using some kind of build tool like [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [Autotools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system). Creating your own Makefiles can be kind of a PITA to get right.

If you have a small directory structure with some C++ files which you want to quickly compile, you can do something like this:

```
find src/ -name "*.cpp" | xargs g++ -I include/
```

Comment: Ah, this looks very much like something useful! However, I get a lot of linker errors with this about multiple definitions. Many of my headers have inline functions, and are included by multiple source files (directly or indirectly). How do I solve this?

Comment: @robrene You use guards in such situation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Hmmm, strange, this can't be the error, since I am using include guards. I was under the impression that they only protect per cpp file (so per object), and not when linking multiple objects together? I'm afraid that's not it...

Comment: @robrene: This looks more like you forgot to use the `inline` keyword.

Comment: @Job: That was the problem! I thought the compiler would automatically inline the function seeing it was in a header file, I guess it only automatically inlines functions defined inside the class definition scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to use an IDE - for example [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) will generate Makefiles for you ([other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93326/which-ide-is-best-for-c) IDEs are [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987868/does-gcc-have-a-gui)).